# temporal compression of binary data

Tags: data-compression, coding-theory, binary

I have a sequence of source files that are very similar (akin to frames in a video), and each file can be compressed by a codec independently, but there is no temporal compression.

I want to further compress the data by exploring the temporal correlation, but I don't know how to do that with the source files. However, since the sources files are quite close, I suspect the compressed data should be close as well. Therefore, I wonder there is any algorithm/software to compress a sequence of similar binary data.

Thanks.

Comment: Any modelling to exploit "self-similarity" will work for concatenated similar sequences. [Lempel-Ziv](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) and [revision control systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) come to mind.

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for the comment. Is there any example of using either of the methods you mentioned to compress a sequence of similar binary data?